# mds_worker taking forever with Time Machine and Monterey

Tags: spotlight

MacBook Air with Monterey 10.5.

After attaching my Time Machine USB drive for my weekly backup, the pure file transfer (a few GB) took less than a minute but afterward `mds_worker` keeps running for hours with no end keeping me from ejecting the volume!

What to do? Spotlight is integrated into Time Machine now and can't be completely switched off right?